# import large data into a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I get an exception when I run this program, its big file filled with data, I am trying to import the data from that file and insert the information into a 2d array, though, the file consists of around 19,000 lines. 
Though, my program stops running and tells me that there are no lines during the process. My exception is  java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found 
                                  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
                               at Data.main(Data.java:30)

Please help, what is wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Data
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try{
      java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/Users/admin/Desktop/data.csv");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);



        String title = in.nextLine();
        String[][] data = new String[19517][5];
        int currentRow = 0;
        String current;


        int i = 0;

       while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[]  c = new String[5];
            String line = in.nextLine().replaceAll("\"", "");  //changing the format of the data input 
            c = line.split(",");
            c[1] = c[1].replace(" ", "");


            for (int j = 0; j <data[0].length; j++)
            {
                current = c[j];
               data[i][j] = c[j];

            }


            i++;
         }



    }
         catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Change `while (i < data.length)` to `while(in.hasNextLine())`

Comment: It doesn't work and it doesn't make a difference, the problem is that it can't detect a line even though lines are present

Comment: Was the csv created in a different OS? You should take care of the difference between "\n" and "\r\n".

Comment: @ChthonicProject doesn't matter here.

Comment: *"it can't detect a line even though lines are present"* I think it just that you have read up all lines.

Answer (score 2):

See [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html):

> Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that
>   **there are no more elements in the enumeration**.

Meaning that you are trying to read a non existing data. This happens because your condition in the `while` loop is always satisfied, causing the `nextLine` trying to read non existing lines. You should change your `while` loop to:

```
while(in.hasNextLine())
```

That ensures `nextLine` will be applied *only* if there are lines to read.
I made a dummy `csv` file and it did read all the lines.

Using a debugger will help you a lot, I highly recommend you to use it.

Comment: i used while(in.hasNextLine()) but it still didn't work

Comment: @RoyKesserwani But now you have a different problem, not this exception right?

Comment: @RoyKesserwani You aren't logging it anywhere to check if it enters the loop, probably check that first

Comment: this is frustrating, Ok I have changed it to in.hasNextLine() but when I want to print data[15000][0], it prints out null even though it's not supposed to

Answer (score 1):

There isn't 19518 lines in your file and in your code you ask it to read that many. (Title + 19517 = 19518).

Never hardcode the number of lines you **expect** in a file. If you hardcode a number, then hardcode the minimum number that you **need** for your code to work.